# After git revert, merge showing no changes and already updated

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-remote, git-revert

I have a `dev` branch which already merged with branches `featureA` and `featureB`.
I merged that `dev` branch to `master` and pushed to remote. Later I identified `featureB` is not yet ready to merge with `master` as there is a faulty commit. So I revert that merge of  `dev` --> `master`.

```
git revert -m 1 <merge-commit-hash>
```

Then I am trying to merge `featureA` to `master`. But I cannot merge. It will say `Already up to date`.

I know the reason as Linus Torvalds said,

> Linus explains the situation:
>
> Reverting a regular commit just effectively undoes what that commit
>       did, and is fairly straightforward. But reverting a merge commit also
>       undoes the *data* that the commit changed, but it does absolutely
>       nothing to the effects on *history* that the merge had.
>
> So the merge will still exist, and it will still be seen as joining
>       the two branches together, and future merges will see that merge as
>       the last shared state - and the revert that reverted the merge brought
>       in will not affect that at all.
>
> So a "revert" undoes the data changes, but it's very much *not* an
>       "undo" in the sense that it doesn't undo the effects of a commit on
>       the repository history.
>
> So if you think of "revert" as "undo", then you're going to always
>       miss this part of reverts. Yes, it undoes the data, but no, it doesn't
>       undo history.

In this situation only solution to merge that `dev` again to `master` is `revert the revert commit`. But I only want to merge the one branch included in `dev` branch, that is `featureA`

How can I merge the branch (`featureA`) to mainline branch (`master`), that included in reverted merge branch (`dev`)  ?

Comment: Same issue, no answers anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do a revert of the whole `develop` to `master` merge here, but do a revert of the 1 specific branch instead. In your case it should be a revert of `featureB` to `develop` merge.

**If your revert cannot be undone, simplest solution is to revert it back and do a new revert of `featureB` to `develop` merge only. Otherwise, I would recommend to get rid of the initial revert and follow the explanation below.**

Let's draw what happens here according to the description:

```
  master   a------------------M3
            \                /    
     dev     b-------M1-----M2
             |\     /      /
featureA     | c---d      /
              \          /
featureB       e--------f
```

here `M3` is merge commit you're trying to revert by:

```
git checkout master
git revert -m 1 <M3-commit-hash>
```

If you did exactly what you said, by the command above you doing revert of the whole `dev` to `master` merge commit `M3`, which will produce revert commit and will put it after `M3` in timeline:

```
  master   a------------------M3---rvM3
            \                /    
     dev     b-------M1-----M2
             |\     /      /
featureA     | c---d      /
              \          /
featureB       e--------f
```

where `rvM3` is the revert commit of the whole `dev` branch merge.

Then you're trying to execute:

```
git checkout master
git merge featureA
```

Now let's imagine the picture of expected result:

```
  master   a------------------M3---rvM3---(M4)
            \                /            /
     dev     b-------M1-----M2           /
             |\     /      /            /
featureA     | c---d----- / -----------         
              \          /          
featureB       e--------f
```

If take a look carefully on the last view we can found that **commits `c` and `d` from the `featureA` are already a part of the `master` branch after `M3` merge and they are reachable from `M3` by the parent links**.

You may expect that `M4` with commits from `featureA` will be created, but it does not happen, since **to Git there is nothing new to add from the `featureA` branch to `master` (from the commit perspective) as it was already merged before**. It doesn't matter that in fact code changes from the `featureA` are not presented in `master` anymore as Git cares about commits only, not the changes itself and does not care what happens to them in the future commits.

Having that in mind we can come to a simple solution — **what you really need is not a revert of whole `M3` merge, but instead a revert of `M2` only** and picking the branch with `M1` as revert destination for merge commit (assuming it has index 1 in the command):

```
git checkout master
git revert -m 1 <M2-commit-hash>
```

Which will do exactly what you wanted and you will end up with something like that:

```
  master   a------------------M3---rvM2
            \                /    
     dev     b-------M1-----M2
             |\     /      /
featureA     | c---d      /
              \          /          
featureB       e--------f
```

where `rvM2` holds changes from the `M2` discarding ones that came from `e` and `f` commits.

Generally, **every time we want to revert something it's better to be as specific as possible**. I.e. if we want to revert 1 commit, we need to execute revert only for it, not the whole branch holding it, and if we want to revert 1 specific branch — we should not revert composite merge of several branches, like you did in `M3` initially.

Comment: did you manually type that branch diagram? If not, could you share what you used? Thanks :)

Comment: I typed that :)